# Disable direct access to nginx custom error page

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, custom-error-pages

I have this nginx block that redirects all 401,403 and 404 to a single custom error page

```
error_page 401 @errorPage;
error_page 403 @errorPage;
error_page 404 @errorPage;
location @errorPage {
    rewrite ^ /error.php?error=$status last;
}
```

Is it possible to deny the access to the error.php if called directly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider storing error pages outside of the main web folder and set a new [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) or [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias):

```
location @errorPage {
  root /var/www/error-pages;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to apply your advice